# Antlr4 Arithmetic Grammar Is Ignoring Order of Precedence (PEMDAS)

Tags: antlr, antlr4

## Grammar Definition

In my understanding ANTLR4 support left recursion to respect order of precedence for arithmetic. With that said here's the grammar:

```
grammar Arithmetic;

arithmetic: arithmeticExpression;

arithmeticExpression:
    LPARAN inner = arithmeticExpression RPARAN                      # Parentheses
    | left = arithmeticExpression POW right = arithmeticExpression  # Power
    | left = arithmeticExpression MUL right = arithmeticExpression  # Multiplication
    | left = arithmeticExpression DIV right = arithmeticExpression  # Division
    | left = arithmeticExpression ADD right = arithmeticExpression  # Addition
    | left = arithmeticExpression SUB right = arithmeticExpression  # Subtraction
    | arithmeticExpressionInput                                     # ArithmeticInput;

arithmeticExpressionInput: NUMBER;

number: NUMBER;

/* Operators */
LPARAN: '(';
RPARAN: ')';
POW: '^';
MUL: '*';
DIV: '/';
ADD: '+';
SUB: '-';

/* Data Types */
NUMBER: '-'? [0-9]+;

/* Whitespace & End of Lines */
EOL: '\r'? '\n';
WS: [ \t]+ -> channel(HIDDEN);
```

> Note: I've simplified the grammar for testing.

## Input

```
5 + 21 / 7 * 3
```

## Output Parse Tree

[image: Output Tree]

## Problem

In the outputted parse tree starting at the `arithmetic`. You can see that the Order of Precedence is not following PEMDAS even though it's defined via left recursion in the grammar. This is also observed when debugging the visitor code generated by Antlr with the function call being `VisitAddition`.

I've google this and I can't see what I'm doing wrong compared to examples as they all look the same.

## Environment

ANTLR Version: 4.11.1

Build Target: CSharp

.NET Project Packages:

1. Antlr4BuildTasks@11.1.0
2. Antlr4.Runtime.Standard@4.11.1

Comment: Can you explain how the result differs from what you want? The fact that multiplication has higher precedence than division?  That's how you've defined it in the grammar. If you want multiplication and division to be at the same level of precedence, you need to define them together in the same alternative (same for plus and minus).

Comment: @sepp2k, sure, I want to follow mathematical order of precedence PEMDAS. However, it's currently not following that order. As when the grammar is parsed its calling Addition before the multiplication which is wrong. This leads to the result being mathematically incorrect when computed.

Comment: The parse tree that you've showed is equivalent to `5 + (21 / (7 * 3))`. The mathematically  correct one would be `5 + ((21 / 7) * 3)`. So the precedence of `+` (relative to `*` and `/`) is fine.

Comment: The usual convention in maths is for `+` to have the same precedence as `-` and `*` the same as `/`. "PEMDAS" should be read as "PE(MD)(AS)" (or just don't use the acronym at all). The grammar you've written is a correct implementation of "PEMDAS" if you interpret it to be a strict ordering. That's just not the right interpretation.

Comment: Got it, my bad. I think in my head I was expecting to see the `VisitX` in the order of precedence (PEMDAS) leading me to think it was parsing in the wrong order! I'll test some more equations and make sure I get the right output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments by @sepp2k (Thank you).

The issue is with the grammar because both the `multiplication`, `division`, `addition` and `subtraction` had been split into seperate `OR` rule lines. Essentially creating PEMDAS when it should be `PE(MD)(AS)`.

Here's an example of the fixed grammar:

```
arithmeticExpression:
    arithmeticExpressionInput                                                           # ArithmeticInput
    | LPARAN inner = arithmeticExpression RPARAN                                        # Parentheses
    | left = arithmeticExpression operator = POW right = arithmeticExpression           # Power
    | left = arithmeticExpression operator = (MUL|DIV) right = arithmeticExpression #
        MultiplicationOrDivision
    | left = arithmeticExpression operator = (ADD|SUB) right = arithmeticExpression #
        AdditionOrSubtraction;
```

and now the outputted parse tree is much cleaner:

[image: Fixed Grammar Pase tree]